# ionic2 taking time to set the form field value dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have implemented the custom qrcode scanner successfully and received the scanning details in the following way.

```
    declare var window: any;
        @Component({
          selector: 'dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'  
        })
        export class DashboardPage { 
           constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)  {
           } 
         public scanAndPayMode(){      
         if (window.npciLib){            
                window.npciLib.qrcodereader('', (data:any) => {
                      this.getAllVPAList(data);                
                 }, function (error:any) { 

             });
          }   
      } 
       public getAllVPAList(scanurl: any){  
         this.commonServices.getAllVirtualList('A').then((result:any)=>{                     
           this.navCtrl.push(IntentPage, {"value": scanurl, "payerObj": result.content});
      }).catch((err: any)=>{     
    })  
  }
 }
```

After scanning, I want to go to the next page where i have payment form containing the pre populated account numbers.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label stacked>Select Virtual Address</ion-label>
   <ion-select [formControl]="vaddr" (ionChange)="fetchName($event)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let vaddrlist of virtualAddrObj" [value]="vaddrlist.accno+'-'+vaddrlist.accname">{{vaddrlist.accno}}</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>              

<ion-item *ngIf="showdebitacc" class="disable-ion-item">
 <ion-label stacked>Debit account number</ion-label>
 <ion-input [formControl]="dbacct" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

It is taking time(nearly 30 sec) to render the account name after selecting specific account (even though fetching data from API with in 2 sec)
Suppose if I tap the select box again(second time), data is displaying.

### ts file

```
public fetchName(vpa: any){
  this.showdebitacc = true;
  this.sendMoneyForm.patchValue({dbacct: vpa.split('-')[1]});
}
```

Could any body help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue using angular NgZone.

```
public scanAndPayMode(){   
      this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular(() => {    
         if (window.npciLib){            
                window.npciLib.qrcodereader('', (data:any) => {
                 this.ngzone.run(() =>{
                      this.getAllVPAList(data);  
                  });               
                 }, function (error:any) { 

             });
          }   
       });
      }
```